# NodeJS Gzip Image compression?

Tags: node.js, express, compression, gzip

Recenlty, I came across the topic of end to end compression, where a file or some data can be compressed by the server and decompressed by the browser.
I'm currently using gzip to compress my files(using nodejs server).
But I see it best fitting to compress text files.
Is there a way to compress Image files using this module? Orr is there another module that can achieve the same thing?

Comment: have a look at `accept-encoding` HTTP header. When a browser makes a request, it can specify a list of accepted encodings (including compressors), web server may automatically compress the resources, and the browser may automatically decompress the resource.

Comment: What sort of format are your images in? Many commonly used image formats are already compressed...